# Call to undefined method in seeder, Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I try to create roles and permissions for users, and I get an error on seeder when I try to assign permissions to roles.

```
//from seeder
    use App\Ability;
    use App\Role;
    use App\User;

    public function run(){
        $owner = Ability::where('name', '=', 'owner');
        $administrator = Role::where('name', '=', 'administrator');
        $administrator->allowTo($owner);
    }

//from my Role Model
     public function abilities()
     {
         return $this->belongsToMany(Ability::class)->withTimestamps();
     }

     public function allowTo($ability)
     {
         $this->abilities()->save($ability);
     }
```

> Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::allowTo()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting the data you are just checking the condition .

Try this and let me know if this helps you

```
//from seeder
    use App\Ability;
    use App\Role;
    use App\User;

    public function run(){
        $owner = Ability::where('name', '=', 'owner')->first();
        $administrator = Role::where('name', '=', 'administrator')->first();
        $administrator->allowTo($owner);
    }

//from my Role Model
     public function abilities()
     {
         return $this->belongsToMany(Ability::class)->withTimestamps();
     }

     public function allowTo($ability)
     {
         $this->abilities()->save($ability);
     }
```